# PHP not return correct number of nodes in XML-file

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to delete certain nodes from an XML-file using PHP, for some reason it was not working properly and I came to the conclusion that that's probably the case, because PHP is not returning the correct number of nodes, that are in said XML-file.

This is the XML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Filenames>
    <newFile>
        <link>somelink</link>
        <ViewLink>someotherlink</ViewLink>
        <FileName>test</FileName>
    </newFile>
    <newFile>
        <link>somelink</link>
        <ViewLink>someotherlink</ViewLink>
        <FileName>test</FileName>
    </newFile>
</Filenames>
```

...and so on (the file is way longer, but I'm always using the same name for nodes etc., you get the point)

Since deleting certain nodes did not work out, I tried just getting the information from the xml-file first and I tried to check how many `<newFile>` (those are the nodes I want to delete) nodes PHP could find.
In order to do that, I did the following:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load("FilenameList.xml");

    $root = $doc->documentElement;

    $newFiles = $root->getElementsByTagName("newFile");
    echo count($newFiles);
?>
```

However, that returned "1", even though, obviously, there are way more nodes.
I also tried counting the amount of `<newFile>`nodes using simpleXML, but again, it did not work. I'm very confused by this, as I used the same syntax in the past and it worked out perfectly.
Another thing I tried was to do this:

```
$newFiles = $doc->getElementsByTagName("newFile");
```

Instead of `$root = ...`

In addition, I also tried using `sizeof()` instead of `count()`.
Am I missing something or does anyone have an idea about what's going wrong?

Comment: to count the number of nodes found, use `->length` attribute, like this `echo $newFiles->length`, `count()` function is not the proper function to use

Comment: ah that was a stupid mistake, I was hoping that there was actually a bigger mistake so I knew why deleting didn't work. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) function returns a new instance of class [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). Such class had the following signature when the question was made:

```
DOMNodeList implements Traversable {
    /* Properties */
    readonly public int $length ;
    /* Methods */
    DOMNode DOMNodelist::item ( int $index )
}
```

The class implemented the [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface (so you can `foreach ()` it) but not the [Countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interface, which would allow `count()` to produce something useful.

The solution is the `$length` property you can see in the class signature:

> `length`
>
> The number of nodes in the list. The range of valid child node indices
>   is 0 to length - 1 inclusive.

As of [PHP/7.2.0](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.0) the `Countable` interface was finally implemented:

> **DOM:**
>
> Implemented FR [#74837](http://bugs.php.net/74837) (Implement Countable for DomNodeList and
>   DOMNamedNodeMap).

Current version of the documentation is this:

```
DOMNodeList implements Traversable , Countable {
    /* Properties */
    readonly public int $length ;
    /* Methods */
    public int count ( void )
    DOMNode item ( int $index )
}
```

… and your original code should finally work.

Comment: This does not explain why the documentation page I am currently seeing states that DOMNodeList would in fact implement `Countable` and thus has a `count()` method, without any hint if this has only been implemented in recent PHP versions (I am using 7.0.30, which does not implement the interface).

Comment: @Sven Thant's for reporting. It shows up in the [changelist for PHP/7.2.0](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.0): *Implemented FR #74837 (Implement Countable for DomNodeList and DOMNamedNodeMap).*

Comment: You are right, and the documentation is wrong, the change came to life with 7.2.0 as you said. I tried to edit the docs, but I feel the change may have not been saved.

Answer (score 1):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML("FilenameList.xml");
$newFiles = $doc->getElementsByTagName('newFile');
foreach ($newFiles as $newFile) {
   $newFile++;
}
echo $newFile;
```

you forgot the foreach loop. Check this http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php